# Add element into Array

Tags: bash, shell

I´m trying to dynamically add an element into an array:

```
   array=("element1" "element2" "element3")
   fa=()
   # now loop through the above array
   for i in "${array[@]}"
   do
      fa+=("$i")
      # or do whatever with individual element of the array
   done

   echo $fa
```

But it's returning `element1`.

I've tried with an index, but I'm getting the same result:

```
fa[index]="$i"
((index++))
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: A side-note, you may double check whether all the shells support `fa+=("$i")` style.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is with printing ie `echo $fa`. This is equivalent to `echo ${fa[0]}` which means the first element of the array, so you got`element1`

```
echo "${fa[@]}"
```

should give you the entire array.

**Reference**

[[ This ]](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html) should give you a nice description about bash arrays.